# How to get the derivative from this implicit equation with differentials?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The idea is here to have a implicit equation and take from both sides of the  equation the **differential** and solve out of this the derivative

The derivative is the ratio of two differentials and can be thought of as a fraction : dy/dx

`eqn = Dt[x*y^3 + Sin[x + y]] == Dt[2]`

note:  (dx+dy) = d(x+y) ( a calculation rules of differentials (one of them))

Using Solve for getting dy and dy is not working ?

The desired expression must be dy/dx = .....

Comment: An equation has 2 sides, you only specify one.

Comment: Thanks, yes i did first for Solve[ eqn, Dt[x]] , but Solve gives a error

Comment: I do see now what you mean: i forget the RHS

Comment: I added it later the RHS in post .. you are right , thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
expr = y^3 Dt[x] + 3 x y^2 Dt[y] + Cos[x + y] (Dt[x] + Dt[y])

(Dt[y] /. First@Solve[expr == 0, Dt[y]])/Dt[x] // Simplify
```

> -((y^3 + Cos[x + y])/(3 x y^2 + Cos[x + y]))

$$-\frac{\cos (x+y)+y^3}{3 x y^2+\cos (x+y)}$$

Comment: Syed thanks great. On this code I would not come up with myself. 
Its not clear why this expr must be zero ( homogen? )
But, wait i see i forget something in my example!
In my example to get the derivative from an implicit equation ( two methods) and this is via by taken the differentials from both sides of the equation.
Its not 0, but it is 2 in the differential equation

Comment: This will work for separable equations only. I chose 0 as I wanted to `Solve` and it needs an equation.

Comment: Ah , yes the differential of a number (contant) is 0. A differential equation with variables to be separated is this type.